# Optimum Weight update in CNN training

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I have two networks. D->C1,R1->P1->C2,R2->loss and D->C1,R1,C2,R2->P1->C3,R3->loss.

D is data, C for Conv, R for Relu and P for Pool.

I trained first network from scratch and since two networks have only C2,R2 layers are different, I used all weights from first network and train only C2. C1 and C3 are set with lr_mult=0.So their weights are not updated.

My query is how can I know C2 has optimum weight to stop training.

Say network 1 has mAP=0.85 after 5 epochs. When I train network 2, it has mAP=0.86 just after 1 epoch.

When should I stop training in such case?

Comment: You should stop when either you're satisfied with the result, or if you think you've reached the network's maximum potential. The latter can only be verified after trying multiple runs, with multiple hyperparameters, such as learning rate. This question is otherwise unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this is different from any other context -- you stop training when you're convinced that continued training will not result in any meaningful improvement. A common way to do this is to monitor some out-of-sample statistic and stop training when that statistic stops improving/starts worsening.